# How to prevent users from accessing a web application from a locally saved Html login page?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, desktop

I have a web application which is used by lots of non-technical users. I have found that several of these users are saving the login page of the application to their desktops (which also saves the associated CSS and JS files). Then, to start using the application, they double click on that desktop icon which shows the local copy using the file:// protocol.

This can cause problems later on, e.g. if I change the login form, or the URL it posts to, etc. Also, certain javascript utilities, e.g. PIE.htc don't work using the file:// protocol.

Obviously what they should be doing is saving a browser bookmark/favorite, I'm looking for a way of detecting and warning those users without confusing the rest. I have been using some javascript to warn these users:

```
if (top.location.protocol == 'file:') {
    alert('This application is not designed to be accessed from a desktop copy...')
}
```

But this will only warn users that have saved the desktop copy since I have added this piece of javascript.

Has anyone else had this problem and come up with clever solutions that they'd like to share?

Thanks

**Update:**

In the end I decided to do this by setting a cookie with a nonce value upon login page request, and storing the same value as a hidden field in the form. Then, in the form submit handler, check that the two are the same and show an error message if not. One could store the nonce in a session instead of a cookie, but I don't want to create unnecessary sessions.

If the user has saved the login page locally, they will likely have different nonce values in the saved form compared to the cookie (if they have a cookie at all).

Normally one wouldn't add CSRF protection (that's sort of what this is) to a login form, but it fulfills my requirements. I read about this technique on The Register, http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/10/02/google_web_attack_protection/, Google implemented similar protection for their login forms, to protect against forging of login requests, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Forging_login_requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe cookies? If site is running with `file:\\` there probably are not any cookies within request. (Of course, now you should add some cookie (session data) on your login page.

Also, read about CSRF http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery and preventing method.

Comment: True, there won't be any cookies on the saved copy. So I can set the cookie on the login form, and check for its presence after login, on the menu page, nice!

Comment: Are you suggesting using a time dependant CSRF token submitted from the login page to the login handler? I guess, just like CSRF protection, I am attempting to detect requests that didn't come from my application, so this would probably also work. I'll try out your suggestions and report back.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is going to be educating the users to use bookmarks instead of saving physical files.

Other than that, there's probably a way to create a shortcut to your URL instead, perhaps during logon?

Comment: That's a good idea, I have seen sites that have 'Add Bookmark' links (which probably use javascript). I will likely implement this, but at this point I need to warn existing users who have already done this.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably check the http referrer on the server side and warn users not coming from your hosted login form.

Edit:

Actually, a vaguely similar question has been asked before and got a good explanation why referrer is not an ideal solution and also provides an alternative solution: [How to check if a request if coming from the same server or different server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410238/how-to-check-if-a-request-if-coming-from-the-same-server-or-different-server)

Comment: I had tried this, it seemed like the ideal solution, but it seems that IE and Chrome (the ones I tested) don't send the referrer when going from file:// to http://

Comment: Isn't it safe to assume that a request with an empty referrer is not coming from your login form unless the user altered the default behavior of their browser? If you are concerned about annoying your users you could warn them once and never again after they confirmed that they understood the implications.

Comment: Good idea, checking for the absence of the referrer would probably work (but also cause some false positives, e.g. the user typed in a URL once logged in), unfortunately I have run into problems working with the referrer header in the past on this application - many users are sitting behind corporate firewalls which strip the referrer header as a security measure in any case. If I don't figure  this out, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Why, don't you, instead of the alert, put a redirect to your page?

```
window.location = 'http://www.yourdomain.com'
```

Or you can also force a reload with `window.location.reload();`

Comment: The question stated that the HTML page had already been saved by the client, hence can't be modified. I was hoping to detect which users were accessing the sight via a locally saved copy. Also, reloading the file:// page would just reload the local copy

Answer (score 0):

Instead of message you may redirect your user to the real page which has login form, or show the help box that will explain that user should save page in such way.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a session variable that is set as a hidden variable in the form.  If that is not there, you redirect to your login form.