# How can I check if a html form was submitted from the correct domain?

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML form which gets submitted to a PHP page for processing.

I would like to confirm on the processing page that the form was submitted from my site instead of somebody else's.

How to make sure requests can only come from pages I served?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410238/how-to-check-if-a-request-if-coming-from-the-same-server-or-different-server

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can be done.

```
<?php
//Make sure your nonce is a number used once, or Random and generated per request.
$_SESSION['formhash'] = md5('any value to be hashed');
?>
<form> <!-- Form to be posted -->
<input type="hidden" name="hashed" id="hashed" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['formhash']; ?>" />
</form>


<!-- After Form is Posted, Probably the another page -->
<?php
if(isset($_POST["hashed"])){


    if($_POST["hashed"]==$_SESSION['formhash']){
      //Process your Form   
    }else{
      //Do SOmething Else   
    }
}
?>
```

You can read this for more info as well [Using a nonce as a security solution in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003563/using-a-nonce-as-a-security-solution-in-php)